# How to wait all async recursive function in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a list from the request body that I want to parse all links in request async.

When all tasks are finished, I then want to return a response, but my response is always empty because none of the async tasks are finishing.

```
var index = 0;
let items = [];

exports.feed = async (req, res) => {
    (async () => {
        await getSiteData(req.body.sites)
    })();

    if(typeof items !== 'undefined' && items.length > 0){
        res.status(200).json(items);
    } else {
        res.status(404).json({ error: "Something went wrong", success: false });
    }
}


async function getSiteData(list){
    try{
        if(index == list.length-1){
            return items;
        }
        
        await parser.parseURL(list[index], async function(err, feed){
            if(err != null){
                console.log(err);
                return false;
            }
    
            items.push(feed.items)
            index++
            await getSiteData(list);
        });
    } catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the `parser.parseURL()` API?  You are using `await` on it, but then passing it a plain callback which looks wrong.  The API should either return a promise or not, not take a callback AND return a promise.  So, it looks like you're misuing that somehow.

Comment: Also, this `(async () =>{
    await getSiteData(req.body.sites)
  })();` is not doing anything useful.  It appears you don't understand how to use promises or await properly.

Comment: I think you should look into the `Promise.all()` method.

Comment: `typeof items !== 'undefined'` will always be true since `items` is an Array and never anything else

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there's no recursion required. It (almost?) never makes sense to recursively process a flat list (Array)

Your main issue is that `parser.parseURL` does NOT return a Promise, therefore `await`ing it makes no sense, since `await` only waits for Promises to settle

So, let's fix that by creating a "promisified" `parser.parseURL`, which is easy with nodes `util.promisify`

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const parseURL = promisify(parser.parseURL);
```

now you can `await parseURL(url)`

if you need to `parse.parseURL` in series, i.e. one at a time

```
async function getSiteData(list) {
    const result = [];
    for (const url of list) {
        const { items } = await parseURL(url);
        result.push(items);
    }
    return result;
}
```

to `parse.parseURL` in parallel

```
function getSiteData(list) {
    return Promise.all(list.map(parseURL));
}
```

> Some people think that this should be

```
async function getSiteData(list) {
    return await Promise.all(list.map(parseURL));
}
```

> I'm not one of those people. Their argument is, `getSiteData` returns a Promise, so should be marked as such, some malarkey about IDE hints or some such garbage. While the code is equivalent (not identical of course), it really isn't necessary in my opinion.

Note: now `getSiteData` (in either series or parallel form) returns a Promise that will resolve to an array of results, and, further more, neither version does any error handling. This is deliberate, so the function that calls `getSiteData` determine what to do with errors.

The other issus is in your `feed` export

```
(async () => {
    await getSiteData(req.body.sites)
})();
//
// the code down here runs without waiting for getSiteData to complete
```

this runs that asynchronous IIFE, but the code afterwards does not wait for it to complete

You could

```
await (async () => {
    await getSiteData(req.body.sites)
})();
```

But then, that's just

```
await getSiteData(req.body.sites);
```

Without the IIFE

Since the `getSiteData` now returns the list (rather than using a "global" or external array to hold the list), the code is now:

```
exports.feed = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const items = await getSiteData(req.body.sites);
        res.status(200).json(items);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(404).json({error: "Something went wrong", success: false});
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue with using for loop and promise.

```
exports.feed = async (req,res) => {
  var items = [];
  for(const elem of req.body.sites){
    const newElement = await getSiteData(elem)
    items.push(newElement)
  }

  if(typeof items !== 'undefined' && items.length > 0){
    res.status(200).json(items);
  }else{
    res.status(404).json({ error: "Something went wrong", success: false });
  }
}


function getSiteData(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(()=>{  
      parser.parseURL(url,   function(err, feed) {
        if(err != null){
          return false;
        }
        resolve(feed.items)
      })    
    
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: *using forEach* no, you don't use `forEach` at all